# Can't complete the Doc sending on Salesforce mobile app/ webseite

Tags: docusignapi

I can't finish sending whether i use the URL button or the lightening component button. And there is some issue I have faced:

1. I can't choose the recipient even that I have a look-up relationship with Contact in my custom Object.
2. The Doc can't be sent after I click next. It shows up a blank page or a button to ask me install your mobile app. ( Under Object "Contact which has default button)
3. I click the "lightening component button" on iPad and it will re-direct to the Salesforce classic page. Is there anything way to keep it running under lightning experience?

Thanks !

demo image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mnktw.jpg